# Web push notification icon with Base64

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-push, workbox

I have implemented a service worker using Workbox library. For web push notification we are using FCM via WebPush (https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp)

Now what I want is to send a dynamic push notification icon. Icons are saved in a database in base64 format. When  I try to send a push from server side using WebPush its throwing an exception: "Bad Request".

So is it possible to used Base64 instead of image URL?

On google's [developer page](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/display-a-notification#icon) it mentionss that "some browsers may require the image be served over HTTPS." So, is that the problem?

I have tried to send base64 to FCM via webPush. It didn't work.

If I hard code the icon with base64 it works.

```
notificationData.icon = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg....'; //its working.

// PUSH NOTIFICATIONS Event
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker]: Received push event', event)

  var notificationData = {}

  if (event.data.json()) {
    notificationData = event.data.json().notification // "notification node is specific for @angular/service-worker
  } else {
    notificationData = {
      title: 'Notification',
      message: 'You got notification',
      icon: './assets/imgs/notificationicon.jpg'
    }
  }
  notificationData.icon = notificationData.icon;
  self.registration.showNotification(notificationData.title, notificationData)
})

//Server Side WebPush
try {
  pushMessage.notification.icon = SystemInfo.Settings.NotificationIcon; // Base64 String
  _client.SendNotification(subscription.ToWebPushSubscription(), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pushMessage), _vapidDetails);
} catch (WebPushException e) {
  _logger.Error(e.Message); // Bad Request
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can't use base64 with push notification as FCM document stats that push message size can't exceed 4 KB.

To resolve this issue, I created an api and replaced image path with Api url. From server side I retrieved base64 from DB and forwarded and It worked.

```
notificationData = {
  title: 'Notification',
  message: 'You got notification',
  icon: '/api/GetImage?id=notificationIcon'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the icon size is smaller. In my case it worked with the icon size as 72px * 72px. No need for a `base64` string.