# Onesignal push notification icon is not showing

Tags: push-notification, onesignal, web-push, android-push-notification, notification-icons

I have added a logo image on one signal push notification settings page for web push. It is not showing a logo image on a push notification in the browser. It is showing the default bell icon.

We have the same issue on android SDK push notification also.

How to fix it?
[Push notification logo settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jho78.png)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/67668287/10802715 if it helps.